# How low can the approval rating of a majority candidate be?

Tags: linear-programming, voting-theory

“Ostrogorski's paradox” describes a strange situation in which voters decide on candidates based on issues in platforms, but on each issue of the platform, the majority of voters disapprove of the majority winner.

> **What is the lowest possible approval rating for a majority winner?**

### Example

For example, if there are 3 issues, then the voters may divide into four camps: one camp of “all issues are important”, and three camps of “only this issue is important, the others detract from it.”  A sample poll may reveal:

\begin{array}{r|rrr}\newcommand{\t}[1]{\text{#1}}
           & \t{Size} & \t{Issue 1} & \t{Issue 2} & \t{Issue 3} \\ \hline
\t{Camp 0} &     40\% & \t{Yes}     & \t{Yes}     & \t{Yes}     \\
\t{Camp 1} &     20\% & \t{Yes}     & \t{No}      & \t{No}      \\
\t{Camp 2} &     20\% & \t{No}      & \t{Yes}     & \t{No}      \\
\t{Camp 3} &     20\% & \t{No}      & \t{No}      & \t{Yes}     \\ \hline
\t{Favored}&          & 60\%\t{ Yes}& 60\%\t{ Yes}& 60\%\t{ Yes}
\end{array}

Candidate A looks at the polls and sees that $60\%$ of people support each issue, and so decides his platform is to support all three issues. Candidate B is contrary and decides his platform is to reject all three issues. The voters in camp 0 vote for A, obviously. The voters in camp 1 see that candidate B agrees with them on 2 out of 3 issues, and so vote for B. Similarly camps 2 and 3 vote for B.

Candidate B wins $60\%$ to $40\%$ a huge margin of victory!  However, once in office, polls reveal that only $40\%$ of voters approve of his handling of issue 1. Similarly for issue 2 and 3. Nobody likes the majority candidate!

### Formal problem

Let $I$ be a finite set (of issues), and $\mathcal{S}=\wp(I)$ be the set of all subsets of issues, so that each $S \in \mathcal{S}$ represents the issues that are supported.  A voter profile is a function $\mu$ from $\mathcal{S}$ to the closed interval $[0,1]$ such that $\sum_{S \in \mathcal{S}} \mu(S) = 1$. An election is a subset $C=\{C_1,C_2\}$ of $\mathcal{S}$ of size 2 (the two candidates) along with a voter profile.  The outcome $O(C_1,C_2,\mu)$ of an election is $$O(C_1,C_2,\mu) = \sum \left\{ \mu(S) : S \in \mathcal{S} ~\mid~ \left|S \oplus C_1 \right| \leq \left|S \oplus C_2\right| \right\}$$
where $S \oplus C_j$ is the symmetric difference of $S$ and $C_j$, that is, the set of elements where $S$ and $C_j$ differ. The approval rating of candidate $C_j$ on issue $i$ is $$A(C_j, i, \mu) = \sum \left\{ \mu(S) : i \notin S \oplus C_j \right\}$$
and the maximum approval rating of candidate $C_j$ is:
$$A(C_j, \mu) = \max\left\{ A(C_j,i,\mu) : i \in I \right\}$$

> **What is the infimum of the maximum approval rating $A(C_1,\mu)$ given that $O(C_1,C_2,\mu)\geq \tfrac12$?**

### Partial result

Let $|I|=2n+1$ be large and set $\mu(I)=0.5$, $\mu(S) = \frac{1}{2 \binom{2n+1}{n}}$ if $|S|=n$, and $\mu(S) = 0$ otherwise; so that half of the voters support every issue and half support just under half of the issues. Let $C_1 = \{\}$ support nothing, and $C_2 = I$ support everything. Then $O(C_1,C_2,\mu) = 0.5$ but $A(C_1,i,\mu)$ is the sum of about half of the $S$ of size $n$:
$$A(C_1,i,\mu) = \sum\left\{ \mu(S) : i \notin S, S \in \mathcal{S} \right\} = \frac{1}{2 \binom{2n+1}{n}} \cdot \binom{2n}{n} = \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{2n+2}{2n+1} \to \frac14$$

This is as bad as I could make it. Is it as bad as possible?

Comment: Great question :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given any $I$, $\mu$ and $C$ with $O(C_1,C_2,\mu)\ge\frac12$, we can modify them as follows without changing the maximum approval rating. First, for all issues $i$ with $A(C_1,i,\mu)\lt A(C_1,\mu)$, we can let voters change their mind on this issue in favour of $C_1$ until $A(C_1,i,\mu)=A(C_1,\mu)$. This doesn't change $A(C_1,\mu)$, and it cannot decrease the majority for $C_1$. Next we can remove all issues on which the candidates agree from the issue set; these issues don't affect the majority, and since $C_1$ now has the same approval rating for all issues, they also don't affect the maximum approval rating. Further (this is just for convenience), we can flip all issues on which $C_1$ is in favour (by negating the question on the ballot) without any substantial change. So now we have $C_1$ against all issues, $C_2$ in favour of all issues, and $C_1$ with the same approval rating for all issues, and the maximum approval rating hasn't changed and the majority hasn't decreased. Since at least half the voters must agree with $C_1$ on at least half the issues it's clear that the maximum approval rating can't be below $\frac14$.

Comment: Looks good. In my first table, put a "How much support does $C_1$ get?" column that is $\mu(S) |S\oplus C_1| / |I|$ (so if they agree on 2/3 of the issue and there are 20% of the people that is 40/3 % support). Now the sum of the right column should be the average of the bottom row. To win, the right column has to sum to be at least 25% by your last sentence.

Comment: @Jack: I think you mean the sum of the right column should be the *complement* of the average of the bottom row? In the bottom row you counted how many agree with $C_2$, not with $C_1$. (In that case $C_1$ is B and $C_2$ is A.)

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. Bad numbering, A/B = C2/C1. At any rate, I like your proof: reduce to a system with some symmetry, then use the "sum of rows is sum of columns trick" on an appropriate table similar to the one above. :-)